# Mips, how to get the second value in one .word using an offset with lw

Tags: assembly, mips

I have this code

```
size:   .word 8 9
```

I would like to get the 9 and store it in a register, so far I have tried this

```
lw $a0, size    
lw $a0, 4(size)
```

But I don't think I am using the right offset number, how do I get the 8 and the 9 from this .word and store them in seperate registers

Comment: That seems correct. What happened when you tried it in your debugger/simulator? Depending on your assembler you might want to write `size+4` instead.

Comment: Should not be a `,` after `8`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To load an address, use `la`, not `lw`. Then, go 4 bytes past it.

```
la $t0, size
lw $a0, 0($t0)  # 8
lw $a1, 4($t0)  # 9
```

Additionally, as @Eraklon said, comma-separate your .word directive:

```
size:
    .word 8, 9
```

Comment: It's unclear whether the missing comma is a typo or not, also some assemblers (e.g. spim) accept it as-is. In any case that should produce an obvious error message. Also some assemblers accept `lw $a0, 4(size)` or the `lw $a0, size+4` and generate appropriate code so you don't have to do the `la` by hand. But yeah, your code works and is the safest bet.